# Cannot get _Post parameters On Prestashop Controller

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am new to Prestashop and I am trying to build a payment gateway module.

It all works fine until I try and get the parameters for the return URL. For some reason the post parameters always comeback as blank or none as existent. I have tried checking on the browser debugger to see if it was actually sending something and all the required data is there.

[image: This is the debugger in Firefox]

[image: This is the controller the URL calls]

This is the return URL:
..."index.php?fc=module&module=cashu&controller=fail"

---

### Response for sarcom

-Updated code
[image]
-Debugger Get Output
[image]
-Debugger Post Output
[image]

Comment: try to print the $_GET and $_POST vars with: `var_dump($_GET); var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @sarcom I updated the code and it seems that it gets the parameters for the $_GET but not the $_POST. You can see the images on the updated post above.

Comment: Why you have a 302 redirect first?

Comment: @sarcom I'm guessing that is just how the payment getaway is set up to respond. My Web dev is not so strong so any help will be appreciated. Also after doing some digging I found out that 302 redirects tend to act like this when the source is not in HTTPS form. I am currently doing all of this on a LOCALHOST.

Comment: @sarcom I'm just guessing here. But I have my computer set up to redirect traffic from a certain url that I chose to localhost because the payment gateway would not take a url that did not include "www". Would that in turn cause a 302 redirect? causing it lose it's parameters?